# Regarding overriding equals method in java

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

I tried to override equals and hashcode methods in a class. It is a subclass of another class which does not implement the equals method and hashCode methods.

Eclipse gave the below warning .

```
  The super class ABC does not implement equals() and hashCode() methods.
  The resulting code may not work correctly.
```

Why is the above warning given ? Under what circumstances it may not work correctly ?

Comment: A good overview: http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you say `a.equals(b)` versus `b.equals(a)` it is reasonable to expect the behaviour to be the same. But if they are of corresponding types `B` and `A` related by inheritance and only one of them properly implements `equals` then the behaviour will be different in those two examples.

Here, `A` is the superclass and does not implement `equals` at all (so it inherits `java.lang.Object.equals`). Subclass `B` overrides `equals` to depend on the `name` field.

```
class A {

  String name;

  public A() {
    this.name = "Fred";
  }

}

class B extends A {

  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    A a = (A)o;
    return a != null && a.name.equals(this.name);
  }
}

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();

    System.out.println(a.equals(b) == b.equals(a));
  }
}
```

Unsurprisingly, the output is `false`, thus [breaking symmetry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: I disagree. Can you construct an example where the symmetry can be broken if the superclass doesn't implement `equals`? I'm fairly sure the warning message is invalid. Every example of broken symmetry I've seen has always required the super class to define `equals`.

Comment: Well... not really. Why would an `equals` method in the `B` class cast the object to `A`? Don't get me wrong - it's quite *possible* to produce an example that breaks symmetry, but every example I've seen has (deliberate) major faults.

Comment: (FYI - see this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236708/what-will-go-wrong-when-superclass-does-not-redeclare-equals-and-hashcode)

Comment: @DuncanJones - just to make sure I'm not going crazy, do you still believe *Every example of broken symmetry I've seen has always required the super class to define equals*? And re: *Why would an equals method in the B class cast the object to A* - because the newbie coder wants to be able to test equality between *B* and *A* and didn't think it through very carefully, perhaps? This is why helpful tools tell you what you did wrong...

Comment: @DuncanJones - From your comments on that other question: *The super class has no equals method. So none of your examples are relevant.* All classes have an `equals` method - sometimes they inherit it, and sometimes (therefore) it's wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "the super class does not override equals".

Comment: Regarding your first issue - yes, I'm yet to see what I would consider a "real" symmetry problem unless the superclass overrides equals. The classic examples in literature are all triggered when the superclass has overriden equals.

Comment: You're asserting that the example I gave couldn't possibly happen by accident or due to a misunderstanding from a beginner? That's really all these warnings are about.

Comment: No, I think your example could happen. I'm just not convinced the warning message is aimed at beginners writing poor equals methods, given the lack of advice doled out by Eclipse in other scenarios. I remain convinced that it's an erroneous message created by someone who slightly misunderstands the literature in this subject. We'll never know for sure without asking the developers - I may raise a bug to trigger the debate. I'll post a link if I do.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried super class override the equals ... and then auto generate subclass override implementation...

I am sure it will be differnt. it will have call to super.equals()

in current auto generated implementation it is only checking values in child class..

Consider below scenario and you will understand why warning.

```
abstract Class A{
 private int a;
public void setA(int a){
this.a=a;
}
}

Class B extends A{
 private int x;
public void setX(int x){
this.x=x;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) { // This does not call Super.equals
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    B other = (B) obj;
    if (x != other.x)
        return false;
    return true;
}

}
```

and in main Method try

```
B b1= new B();
b1.setA(10);
b1.setX(20);


B b2= new B();
b2.setA(20);
b2.setX(20);

if(b1.equals(b2)){
 System.out.println("Warning was Right");
}
```