# What will go wrong when superclass does not redeclare equals() and hashCode()?

Tags: java

Suppose there are two classes like this:

```
abstract class A { /* some irrelevant methods */ }

class B extends A {
    public final int x;

    public B(final int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    /* some more irrelevant methods */
}
```

Then I generate the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods on class `B` using Eclipse's "Source → Generate hashCode() and equals()...". But Eclipse warns me that:

> The super class 'com.example.test2.A' does not redeclare equals() and hashCode() - the resulting code may not work correctly.

So, **what will make the resulting code not working correctly with the generated methods?**

---

(BTW, the generated methods look like this:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + x;
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    B other = (B) obj;
    if (x != other.x)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

)

Comment: This may be of interest. That said, I am not sure how it applies since A is abstract. http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html. Mostly, it tries to prevent that `b.equals(a)` but `!a.equals(b)`

Comment: I think your question has suffered due to the plethora of literature that explain a very similar, but crucially different scenario. Almost every answer below talks about the super class having an `equals` method, whereas in your example it clearly doesn't. I'm not even the question asker and I'm getting frustrated here!

Comment: @KennyTM is the warning still generated if you remove the abstract modifier?

Comment: @monkybonk05 Yes, it is.

Answer (score 10):

You must be careful when overriding equals to adhere to a specific set of rules. See the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) for details. In short, two tricky parts are preserving symmetry and transitivity. According to Joshua Block's [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)

> "There is no way to extend an instantiable class and add a value component while preserving the equals contract"

What does this mean? Well let's say you have in class A a property of type T and in subclass B another property of type V. If both classes override equals then you'll get different results when comparing A to B than B to A.

```
A a = new A(T obj1);
B b = new B(T obj1, V obj2);
a.equals(b) //will return true, because objects a and b have the same T reference.
b.equals(a) //will return false because a is not an instanceof B
```

This is a violation of symmetry. If you try and correct this by doing mixed comparisions, you'll lose transitivity.

```
B b2 = new B(T obj1, V obj3);
b.equals(a) // will return true now, because we altered equals to do mixed comparisions
b2.equals(a) // will return true for the same reason
b.equals(b2) // will return false, because obj2 != obj3
```

In this case b == a, b2 ==a, b != b2, which is a problem.

*EDIT*

In an effort to more precisely answer the question: "what will make the resulting code not working correctly with the generated methods" let's consider this specific case. The parent class is abstract and does not override equals. I believe we can conclude that the code is safe and no violation of the equals contract has occurred. This is a result of the parent class being abstract. It cannot be instantiated, therefore the above examples do not apply to it.

Now consider the case when the parent class is concrete and does not override equals. As Duncan Jones pointed out, the warning message is still generated, and in this case seems correct to do so. By default, *all* classes inherit equals from Object, and will be compared based on object identify (i.e. memory address). This could result in a unsymmetrical comparison if used with a subclass that does override equals.

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B(T obj1);
a.equals(b) //will return false, because the references do not point at the same object
b.equals(a) //should return false, but could return true based on implementation logic.
```

If b.equals(a) returns true for whatever reason, either implementation logic or programming error, a loss of symmetry will result. The compiler has no way to enforce this, hence, a warning is generated.

Comment: Check this link http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html. Basically, the subclass can ensure that superInstance.equals(subInstance) is false, by the mechanism proposed there.

Comment: *"There is no way to extend an instantiable class…"* — But class `A` is abstract.

Comment: If that was true/related to the warning, you would get the warning either if the superclass was implementing equals or if it was not.

Comment: I see your point and will delete that comment. But I still feel this explains why "the resulting code may not work correctly" and that you should thoroughly test any implementation of equals especially when dealing with inheritance

Comment: Your answer does not apply to this case. The super class has **no** equals method. So none of your examples are relevant.

Comment: @monkybonk05 I'm still not convinced. Not comparing class types is such a fundamental error in an `equals` method, I'm not sure it's a worthy example.

Comment: @Duncan Jones but as I showed in the transitivity example, a misguided attempt to do mixed comparisons would accept super classes in the comparison. This would be incorrect, but the compiler cannot enforce it.

Comment: @monkybonk05 But again, that relies on the super class defining `equals`! Sorry, but I remain firmly in the position that the warning is erroneous as I've yet to see an example of how it can go wrong (other than due to very poor `equals` method in the subclass).

Answer (score 9):

I think this warning is erroneous. Every piece of literature I've ever seen regarding `equals` construction (including Item 8 from Bloch), warns about situations where the parent class *does* implement equals.

Given that your `A` class is solely using reference equality, I cannot fathom a situation where your `B` `equals` method violates any of the required principles (symmetry, transitivity and reflexivity).

Bear in mind that *any* half-sensible `equals` method will have a type check. This is true of the auto-generated code in the original question:

```
if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
    return false;
```

Rather than just quoting chunks of Bloch's book and other websites, we should think long and hard about whether any of the "standard" equals problems are possible if the parent class doesn't implement equals. I would say they're not and I welcome a counter-example.

Comment: Superclass A does not implement equals, subclass B implements it (by checking `id`, say) So, there can be instances where b.equals(a) because the `id` matches, but !a.equals(b) because they are different objects.

Comment: @SJuan76 Only with a poorly coded `equals` method that doesn't compare class types.

Comment: Check the link I provided for a better explained example of how can happen in a not so poorly coded implementation.

Comment: @SJuan76 Yes, but that link is only valid if the super class defines an equals method. Which isn't the case in this question.

Comment: @monkybonk05 My thoughts are unchanged, I'm afraid :-)

Answer (score 1):

If both parent and child classes implement `equals` in such a way that it is not possible for two references to be considered equal unless both refer to instances of the same exact class, there won't be any inheritance-related problems with `equals`.

The problematic situation occurs when it is possible to have instances which are of different classes but are nonetheless supposed to compare equal.  The only proper way to handle that situation is to specify that any instances which may compare equal to each other must derive from a common class, and the contract for that class must specify what equality is supposed to mean.  The common class `equals` (which may or may not be abstract) will typically define virtual members which derived classes can override to test different aspects of equality.  If, for example, the common-class `equals` method is something like `if (other==null) return false; else return this.equals2(other) && other.equals2(this);`, that will essentially guarantee symmetric behavior for any implementation of `equals2` which does not mutate the objects being compared.

Answer (score -3):

Having waited for a time for a convincing reason, my take.

The article I linked (again, it is http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html) explains why there are issues when implementing equals in a subclass (mostly, that the `instanceof` check leads to asimmetries that are forbidden by the `equals` contract).

If your superclass does not implement equals, you may find this situation.

- B extends A
- B implements `equals`, lets say like

  ```
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    A a = (A) obj;  <-- this cast is the most problematic issue from this example
    return this.id.equals(a.getId());
  }
  ```

So you end with

```
A a = new A("Hello");
B b = new B("Hello");
a.equals(b) != b.equals(a);
```

One point that would go against this example is that your superclass is abstract, but probably Eclipse is issuing the warning in prevention that you instantiate it (or it is just that the warning check is not so fine-grained).

Comment: As A is Abstract, eclipse wont provide warning for this reason. the actual reason for warning see my answer

Comment: I think your equals example is unnecessarily poor. Why would an equals method in a `B` class cast the object to `A`? Core to any sensible equals method is a class check. I feel you've massaged your example to fit what you think is the answer.

Comment: @Duncan I'm pretty sure you're right (despite nobody agreeing with you). A superclass not implementing `equals` is surely no problem (`Object` doesn't implement it either). Overriding a non-trivial `equals` may be a problem as explained in the article linked, but they give an universal solution (`canEqual`). Unfortunately, the article is rather confusingly written.