# Overriding hashcode and equals method in java?

Tags: java, equals, hashcode, java-ee-7

I have the classes below:

```
public class Sample implements java.io.Serializable{

  //POJO with two fields and getters/setters

   private String name;
   private Integer id;

   //This POJO does not override equals() and hashCode()
}

public class B{
 private Sample sample;

  //here i need override hashcode and equals() based on **sample** property.


}
```

When i tried overriding equals() and hashCode() in the **B** class I got the error below in Eclipse.

> The field type com.mypackage.Sample does not implement hashCode()  and equals() - The resulting code may not work correctly.

Now how can I compare two **B** instances whether equals or not based on the Sample property?
I cannot modify Sample class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What will go wrong when superclass does not redeclare equals() and hashCode()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236708/what-will-go-wrong-when-superclass-does-not-redeclare-equals-and-hashcode). Although note that in my opinion, [the warning is erroneous](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16237663/474189).

Comment: Eclipse is a nanny. It worries on your behalf. Ignore it or add the methods to Sample.

Comment: Aware of comparator and comparable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you looking something like following? Just try it, as from your question i think you want to compare contents of your Sample class also.

```
class Sample implements java.io.Serializable{

    //POJO with two fields and getters/setters

    private String name;
    private Integer id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    //This POJO does not override equals() and hashCode()
}

public class Beta implements Comparable{
    private Sample sample;

    public Sample getSample() {
        return sample;
    }

    public void setSample(Sample sample) {
        this.sample = sample;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {

        if(!(o instanceof Beta)){
            return -1;
        }
        }if(((Beta)o).getSample().getName().equals(this.sample.getName())){
                return 0; // return true if names are equal
            }
            if(((Beta)o).getSample().getId().equals(this.sample.getId())){
            //if name are notequal and IDs are equal, do what you need to do
            }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Beta b = new Beta();
        Sample s = new Sample();
        s.setId(10);
        s.setName("Name1");
        b.setSample(s);

        Beta b2 = new Beta();
        Sample s2 = new Sample();
        s2.setId(20);
        s2.setName("Name2");
        b2.setSample(s2);

        System.out.println(b2.compareTo(b));

        Beta b3 = new Beta();
        Sample s3 = new Sample();
        s3.setId(10);
        s3.setName("Name1");
        b3.setSample(s3);

        System.out.println(b3.compareTo(b));
    }
}
```

**Overriding approach**

```
class Sample implements java.io.Serializable{

    //POJO with two fields and getters/setters

    private String name;
    private Integer id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    //This POJO does not override equals() and hashCode()
}

public class Beta /*implements Comparable*/{
    private Sample sample;

    public Sample getSample() {
        return sample;
    }

    public void setSample(Sample sample) {
        this.sample = sample;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Beta other = (Beta) obj;

        if ((this.getSample() == null) && (other.getSample() == null)){
            return true;
        }
        if ((this.getSample().getId().equals(other.getSample().getId())) && (this.getSample().getName().equals(other.getSample().getName()))) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 53 * hash + (this.getSample().getName() != null ? this.getSample().getName().hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 53 * hash + (this.getSample().getId() != null ? this.getSample().getId().hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }


/*  @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {

        if(!(o instanceof Beta)){
            return -1;
        }
        if(((Beta)o).getSample().getId().equals(this.sample.getId()) && ((Beta)o).getSample().getName().equals(this.sample.getName())){
            return 0;
        }
        return -1;
    }*/

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Beta b = new Beta();
        Sample s = new Sample();
        s.setId(10);
        s.setName("Name1");
        b.setSample(s);

        Beta b2 = new Beta();
        Sample s2 = new Sample();
        s2.setId(20);
        s2.setName("Name2");
        b2.setSample(s2);

        System.out.println(b2.equals(b));

        Beta b3 = new Beta();
        Sample s3 = new Sample();
        s3.setId(10);
        s3.setName("Name1");
        b3.setSample(s3);

        System.out.println(b3.equals(b));
    }
```

Comment: VD, yes exactly this is what i was looking for.My requirement is first i need to check equals property against "name" property of Sample. IF names are equals then both objects are equal. If names are not equals then i need to check for equality against "ID" property of Sample. How can i do that? Thanks!

Comment: i have edited the code for your requirement, you can refer overriding approach from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180430/how-to-override-equals-method-in-java

Comment: i have also edited the code for overriding hashcode and equals methods

Answer (score 1):

If you don't explicitly override `.equals()`, they will be compared based solely off of their references (despite not having a `equals()`, every object inherits one from `Object`).  If you only want `B` to be compared based off of `Sample`, then simply do the following:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o)
{
     if (o istanceof B)
     {
         return sample.equals(o.sample)
     }

     return false;
}
```

Additionally, you should then override `hashCode()` (and `compareTo()`) to maintain the [contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) between `equals()` and `hashCode()`.  Hence, you should also have the following:

```
@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    return sample.hashCode();
}
```

**EDIT (in response to comment):**

> My requirement is first i need to check equals property against "name"
>   property of Sample. IF names are equals then both objects are equal.
>   If names are not equals then i need to check for equality against "ID"
>   property of Sample. How can i do that? Thanks!

Determining whether `Samples` are equivalent should be handled in `Sample`, by overriding `equals()`.  If `equals()` for `Sample` bases off of `name` and `id`, then you're fine. If you want to compare `Samples` in `B` differently than they are normally compared, then you're not going to be able to maintain the contract between `equals()` and `hashCode()` for `B` if you use `hashCode()` or `equals()` from `Sample`, which means that your `hashCode()` and `equals()` for `B` should be cannot call `equals()` or `hashCode()` from `Sample`. See this [tutorial](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-write-equals-method-in-java.html) for how to override based on specific fields.

Comment: I tried. But still i get "The field type com.mypackage.Sample does not implement hashCode() and equals() - The resulting code may not work correctly". any suggestions?

Comment: @user755806 This definitely works, I believe that your IDE is simply telling you that you're not explicitly overriding `hashCode()` and `equals()`.  Make sure that you have also overridden `hashCode()` for `B`--I made an edit stating how to do this.  If this is not done, then you will not be maintaining the contract of `equals()` and `hashCode()`.  If your IDE still yells at you, it's just a warning to make sure that you understand that for `Sample` you're using the default methods instead of overriding.

Comment: Steve, thanx for your reply. My requirement is first i need to check equals property against "name" property of Sample. IF names are equals then both objects are equal. If names are not equals then i need to check for equality against "ID" property of Sample. How can i do that? Thanks!

Comment: @user755806 You're asking multiple questions here...This should be handled in `Sample`.  As in overriding `equals()` from `Sample`.  If this is not the way that `Samples` should normally be compared, or you are unable to do that, then you're **not** going to be able to maintain the `equals()` and `hashCode()` contract, which means that you cannot do what you want to do.  See this [tutorial](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-write-equals-method-in-java.html) for how to override based on specific fields.