# overriding equals and hashcode methods in java?

Tags: java, hashcode, java-ee-7

I have below class.

#### Request.java

```
public class Request implements Serializable {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String hid;

    // getters and setters 

    // This class does not override any equals() and hashCode() methods
}

public class EmpRequest implements Serializable {
    private Request request;
    //Now here in this class I need override equals() and hashCode() methods based on **request**
}
```

In EmpRequest class, I need to **override `equals()` and `hashCode()` based on properties** of **Request** object.

If two request objects **id** is equal then i need to return **true**.
If two objects ids are not equal then i need to check for **name** and **hid** properties.
If name and hid properties of both the objects are equals then i need to return true.
Else false

How can I do that? I tried overriding `equals()` and `hashCode()` but eclipse gave me below the warning.

> The field type 'com.mycompany.Request' does not implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` - the resulting code may not work correctly.

At the same type I cannot modify **Request** class as I don't have control over it.

How can I write `equals()` and `hashCode()` considering above conditions?

Comment: @SachinPasalkar This is not the answer.

Comment: @SachinPasalkar you should mind full when you put a comment. Any of your comment want help for OP. you can just leave here if you don't have any idea

Comment: @SachinPasalkar I understand your rage and passion, but "Read java book first" is at best lame.

Comment: @SachinPasalkar does he asked about teach me java?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20493208/overriding-hashcode-and-equals-method-in-java/20493800#20493800

Comment: @SachinPasalkar OP doesn't asked to learn `Java`. I  think you are overrated your self. No one here became genius by birth, you should learn to respect all who got higher as well as lower reputation people than you

Comment: @user755806 look at my edit. now only EmpRequest implements equals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

```
public class Request implements Serializable{

     private String id;
     private String name;
     private String hid;

        public String getId()
        {
            return id;
        }

        public String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }

        public String getHid()
        {
            return hid;
        }
}

    public class EmpRequest implements Serializable{
         private Request request;

        public Request getRequest()
        {
            return request;
        }

         @Override 
         public boolean equals(Object obj) {
             if(obj==null)
                 return false;
             if(((EmpRequest) obj).getRequest().getId().equals(this.getRequest().getId()))
                 return true;
             else if(((EmpRequest) obj).getRequest().getName().equals(this.getRequest().getName())
                     &&((EmpRequest) obj).getRequest().getHid().equals(this.getRequest().getHid())) {
                 return true;
             }
             else
                 return false;
         }
    }
```

Here is the hashcode too:

```
@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((getRequest().getId() == null) ? 0 : getRequest().getId().hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((getRequest().getName() == null) ? 0 : getRequest().getName().hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((getRequest().getHid() == null) ? 0 : getRequest().getHid().hashCode());
    return result;
}
```

Comment: kai, i cannot implement equals() and hashCode() in my Request class.It is third party class. I have to do it in EmpRequest class.

Comment: Request class is not my own class and i cannot modify it. It is provided by third party. Thanks!

Comment: kai, thanks for your answer. i understood equals(). How can i write hashCode() in this case? do i need to generate hashcode based on the properties of Request class ? Thanks!

Comment: kai, while generating the hashCode(), what if getRequest() itself is null? how to deal in null scenario? thanks!

Comment: oh i forgot this scenario. You can add a if condition and if getRequest() is null, return 1.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your `equals` **is not transitive** and is **incompatible with** the `hashCode`. I guess, the OP's requirements are impossible to satisfy, but your answer is nonetheless wrong.

Answer (score 2):

you can just generate `equals()` and `hashCode()` from IDE (Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA) . That will enough for your scenario.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Result)) return false;

    Result result = (Result) o;

    if (hid != null ? !hid.equals(result.hid) : result.hid != null) return false;
    if (id != null ? !id.equals(result.id) : result.id != null) return false;
    if (name != null ? !name.equals(result.name) : result.name != null) return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (hid != null ? hid.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Ruchira, i need to write it based on Request object properties in EmpRequest.

Comment: `equals()` and `hashCode()` are the properties which related to object it self. you have to implement those inside that object. Not any where else.

Comment: @user755806 when we doing a coding it is a good practice to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()`. That's depends on IDE warning level actually.

Comment: Ruchira, do i need to generate hashcode based on the properties of Request class? Thanks!

Comment: @user755806 If you want to consider about Request class, yes it is.